# How to allow access based on the user meta flag

Tags: users, wp-login-form, authentication

I want to check user meta data and allow access. where I am inserting user_status in `wp_usermeta` table at the time of Registration. How to validate/verify meta value with password for login.

Here is my code in function.php file in child theme:

```
add_action('wp_login' ,'_user_login');
function _user_login($login )
{
$user = get_user_by('login', $login);        
if ( !$user ) {        
    return;
}
$user_id=$user->ID;
$status = get_user_meta($user_id, 'afs_user_status', true);   
if($status=='INACTIVE')
{        
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();                
    $login_url = site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login' );
    $login_url = add_query_arg( 'disabled', '1', $login_url );
    wp_redirect( $login_url );
    exit;
}
}

add_filter( 'login_message','afs_user_login_message');
function afs_user_login_message( $message ) 
{
// Show the error message if it seems to be a disabled user
if ( isset( $_GET['disabled'] ) && $_GET['disabled'] == 1 ) 
    $message =  '<div id="login_error">' . apply_filters( 'afs_disable_users_notice', __( 'Account disabled', 'afs_disable_users' ) ) . '</div>';

return $message;
}
```

Comment: What are you allowing access to? If a user has just registered there won't be any user meta to verify as it hasn't been added yet. What is the `user_status` you referred to? Please edit your question to explain these things, and add any code you have written

Comment: @TomJNowell I have added code. Can you check and suggest.